# Consider the set $W=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}|x^2-y^2=0 \right\}$ Is it a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that for a set to be a subspace must hold that:

a) $0_{v}$ must be in $W$.

b) if $u,v\in W$, then $u+v\in W$

c) If $u\in W$ and $k$ is a scalar, then $k\cdot u$ is in $W$

For a) since $(0,0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, the condition is satisfied. But I'm not really sure how to proceed with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(1,1)+(1,-1)=(2,0) \notin W$.

Answer (score 2):

Almost always the subsets not given by linear equations are not subspaces (maybe there is some exotic example) because you can find a combination of vectors in the subspace such as is not contained in it. For example any on the form $(z, z) +(z, -z), $ with $z\not =0$.

Comment: So, I 

could take $x^{2}-y^{2}=0$.

Comment: What Do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, So, as long as I find an inconsistency I can just evaluate in $a=(2, 2)$ and $b=(2,-2)$ with $a+b=(2,2)+(2,-2)=(4,0)$ so $a+b\notin W$. My confusion comes from whether it is necessary to evaluate $x^{2}-y^{2}=0$.

Comment: When you prove that $(4, 0) \not \in W$, since $4^2-0^2\not =0$.

Comment: The idea is that proving that it is a vector space requires proving it generally, while proving it is not a vector space just requires a single counter-example

Comment: So, first find an inconsistency and then evaluate to prove in the equation given so $\notin W$. Thanks!